# Synonyms of Click

Tags: word-request, synonyms

One of the meaning of the word ‘click’ is *to become clear suddenly*. It's like when you are solving a problem and suddenly you understood something.

What's the synonyms for this word? Surprisingly I couldn't find anything on [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/click)

Comment: I find that [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/click.html) is a useful resource for synonyms of various shades of meaning of a word. Although it doesn't have "[a light bulb goes off in (one's) head](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+light+bulb+goes+off+in+(one%27s)+head)."

Comment: Note that many "synonyms" for this metaphoric usage (where ***click*** = ***come together, fall into place*** = *make sense*) come at the process from the opposite end. That's to say, rather than *it became clear **to me***, we can say ***I** realised* - where the grammatical "subject" is the (concrete noun) person gaining insight, not the (abstract noun) insight itself.

Comment: https://www.freethesaurus.com/click

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

- I understood
- It became clear
- it all fell into place
- The penny dropped (chiefly British idiom)
- It dawned on me (refers more to having an idea or realisation than understanding)
- I had a lightbulb moment (usually means having a sudden, good idea)
- it hit/struck me (a realisation, perhaps upon noticing something)

Answer (score -1):

**Eureka!**

I found it, from Ancient Greek.

Eureka (Ancient Greek: εὕρηκα) is an interjection used to celebrate a discovery or invention. It is a transliteration of an exclamation attributed to Ancient Greek mathematician and inventor Archimedes.

[eureka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_(word))

Comment: hey downvoter, sour grapes, huh? It's amazing how envy destroys sites like these. That's very often the elephant in the room.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think the OP needs a verb (*X clicked* 'X became clear')... *Eureka* is more of an exclamation. How would you insert *Eureka!* into that sentence? *It Eureka'ed*?!

Comment: @Void There really is no indication that a verb was asked for. But even if they wanted a verb, one can always make it into a verb phrase. This is just plain old pigheadedness or ignorance. :) You suddenly understood something: Eureka! But the Greek expression doesn't require a verb. However, one can be supplied: I had a eureka moment.